# How to find this variance?

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

$X$ and $Y$ are jointly distributed continuous random variables,where $Y$ is positive valued and $E[Y^2]=6$. If the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y=y$ is $U(1-y,1+y)$,then find $Var(X)$.

The only result I’ve been able to conclude from the given information is that $E[X]=1$. I don’t know how to proceed. Do help.

Comment: Did you use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance?

Comment: I just did,thank you for the hint. Got the answer.

Comment: Then you can answer the question and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

We have,
$f_{\small X\mid Y}(x\mid y) =\frac{1}{2y}~\big[ 1-y<x<1+y\big]$

Then $E[X\mid Y]$ comes out to be $1$.

And $E[X^2\mid Y]$ comes out to be $\frac{Y^2}{3} + 1$.

Hence,$V(X\mid Y)=\frac{Y^2}{3} + 1 - 1^2$

Thus,$$\begin{align}V[X]
&=E[V(X\mid Y)] + V[E(X\mid Y)]
\\&=E[\tfrac{Y^2}{3}] + V(1)
\\&=\frac{6}{3} + 0\\&=2\end{align}$$